# What Hibernate type use for Serializable field in SQLQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

What correct way to add Serializable scalar to java SQLQuery 
I have entity "Entity" one of the field is

```
@Lob
private Serializable properties;
```

where stored HashMap
now I want receive its value

```
session.createSQLQuery("select properties, ..... as "prop" from entity")
.....
.addScalar("prop", ?????)
.setResultTransformer(....)
.list();
```

But don't know what Hibernate type use `SerializableType`, `MapType` or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
    .addScalar("props", SerializableType.INSTANCE);
```

MapType does not seem appropriate. The property is defined as Serializable, not as a Map.